# return a Vector of an generic class type

Tags: java, class, vector, abstract

I am having a Java function, that I want to return a Vector of a generic class type:

```
private static <T extends IReader> Vector<T> Read()
{
    Vector<T> List = new Vector<T>(); // Create new Vector

    // Create new instance of the type T
    T Dataset = new T();
    Dataset.myFunction();

    // Add to the Vector
    List.add(Dataset);

    // return Vector
    return List;
}
```

The mentioned IReader is a very simple abstract class:

```
public abstract class IReader
{   
  abstract public void myFunction();
}
```

The error I am getting while compiling is that T is a type parameter and that a class is required instead:

```
error: unexpected type
                                T Dataset = new T();
                                                ^
  required: class
  found:    type parameter T
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends IReader declared in method <T>Read()
1 error
```

Now I don't know what I did wrong. I can summarize my thoughts: T needs to be derived from IReader, otherwise Java wouldn't be able to find the method "myFunction", which I am calling. Also I need to work with generics here, because the method Read should be able to return a Vector of different kind of classes.
Concerning the compiler error message: When I replace

```
<T>
```

by

```
Class<T>
```

it doesn't work either. So I think I am stuck here.

My question: **How can I make the mentioned function "Read" to return a Vector of a generic type, that is derived from IReader?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A bit offtopic: Are you sure you need a Vector? Usually an ArrayList is a better (quicker) option unless it is going to be accessed by two different threads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a class which implements IReader but has a private no-arg default constructor.Then obviously you cant create Objects using a default constructor.Consider this :-

```
class Example extends IReader {

private Example{

}
@Override
 public void myFunction(){
//your code goes here 
}
}
```

Obviously you cant create instances of class Example outside the class ,in this case

You can do two things:-

1)Use reflection to create objects

```
private static <T extends IReader> Vector<T> Read(Class<T> cl)
{
    Vector<T> List = new Vector<T>(); // Create new Vector

    // Create new instance of the type T
    T Dataset = cl.newInstance();
    Dataset.myFunction();

    // Add to the Vector
    List.add(Dataset);

    // return Vector
    return List;
}
```

2)You can pass an Object of type T and simpy add to the list

```
private static <T extends IReader> Vector<T> Read(T obj)
{
    Vector<T> List = new Vector<T>(); // Create new Vector

    // Create new instance of the type T

    obj.myFunction();

    // Add to the Vector
    List.add(obj);

    // return Vector
    return List;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this just worked perfectly! Additional information: When calling the method Read (in the first example, with reflection), I must do it by Vector<Sometype> V = Read(Sometype.class);

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Java Generics (unlike C++ templates) don't allow you to use constructions like `new T()`. This happens because Generics are considered as syntax sugar, inside JVM these entities are simply references of type Object (unlike Javac a C++ compiler derives a separate instance of code for each instantiation of a template parameter.

Thus you may move creation of an object of a particular type out of the function and pass a reference to a pre-created object or instantiate an object using reflection and explicitly specified object *class* as described on [java generic constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9183288/java-generic-constructors)

Comment: correct explanation.I missed out that generics object creation is not allowed due to type erasure also apart from the reasons I mentioned in my answer